# the d3d9 hook i have work on some computers and crash on some other computers

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-9, d3dx

I need to fix this or create a d3d device, anyone can help me with that? thanks in advance.

```
void** GetOriginalD3DVTable()
{
    // may be more reliable to create a new d3d device and get the vt ptr from that instead of relying on a pattern
    static void** VT = nullptr;

    if (VT == nullptr)
    {
        HMODULE d3d9Module = NULL;

        while (!d3d9Module)
        {
            d3d9Module = GetModuleHandleA("d3d9.dll");
            Sleep(100);
        }

        const void* tempadd = FindPattern(d3d9Module, 0x128000, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>("\xC7\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x86\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x86"), "xx????xx????xx");
        if (tempadd != nullptr)
        {
            VT = *reinterpret_cast<void***>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(tempadd) + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            //maybe we should try to find another pattern?
        }
    }

    return VT;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? How doe's the configuration from the computers with crash differ from the others?

Comment: @user743414 i have no idea. probably they have a different d3d9.dll. not sure though.

Comment: Is `static void** VT = nullptr;` legal?

Comment: yes, nothing wrong with that. @drescherjm

Comment: 32 vs 64 bit application (game) on different PCs? (Yes you should create device instead of finding pattern)

Comment: Keep in mind that such "hooking" is (a) completely unsupported by the platform, and (b) indistinguishable from malware. The only robust solution is [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/), and that's in fact used by malware too.